# Know which UITabBarItem is selected in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

In my app I've to know which UITabBarItem is selected in AppDelegate, because when the app comes up from background I should do some stuff.
I saw that I've to insert code in the method `applicationDidBecomeActive:application`, but how to do that?
I hope you can help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just save an identifier in your UserDefaults and check it when the App is active again.

Comment: It's exactly what I'm trying to do, thank you for help